# Offline maps in web application on Windows.Extract data from .osm.pbf file

Tags: geolocation, maps, location, openstreetmap

We are trying to show offline maps in our web application. 
My basic usage is entering the latitude/longitude on GUI and showing the position of the point.

> Also once I locate a point I want to show some custom information
>   about that point.This can be inserted easily using JavaScript.

However offline maps is where I am struck. After researching a bit I downloaded map area of my interest in the form of

> .osm.pbf

Having done this I am completely lost as to how to now read the data and show it on GUI inside a web application.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The osm.pbf format is used for the raw data in OSM. It does not contain tiles/images. Within an application you usually get the tiles from an online server.

If you want to have the tiles offline, then you should try to either render them yourself (based on the osm data) or cache the tiles you got from the server. To generate your own tiles, you could start with reading [the openstreetmap wiki on offline maps](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Offline_Openstreetmap), [this question on creating maps](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/8279/how-to-create-map-tiles-from-openstreetmap-offline-and-display-it-on-android) and [this blogpost](http://sk53-osm.blogspot.be/2011/08/creating-off-line-openstreetmap-tiles.html). To cache them, you can get some inspiration on how to do it on the openstreetmap wiki (link posted above) or using [this post](http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=7443)